# Supabase Auth not working unless application is refreshed

Tags: react-native, authentication, expo, supabase

I'm currently using supabase auth for users to sign in and sign out into an application I'm working on. I have this simple function that handle signing in:

```
const signIn = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    try {
      const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({ email, password });

      if (error) {
        console.error('SIGN IN ERROR:', error.message);
        // Handle error accordingly, e.g., show an error message to the user
      } else {
        console.log('SIGN IN SUCCESS:', data);
        // Continue with the logic after successful sign-in
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('SIGN IN EXCEPTION:', error.message);
      // Handle unexpected exceptions, e.g., network issues, etc.
    }
}
```

The weird issue that's occurring is that this will only work once. If the user signs out and attempts to sign back in again, then none of the code after the asynchronous call will execute. I can see in flipper that a POST request is being made due to `supabase.auth.signInWithPassword` but the try/catch block ends up not being executed unless I refresh the application. Kind of a weird issue but this started happening as soon as I created an Auth Provider to handle sharing the user info across the entire application.